# Reading Specific Text from a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

Hello I am currently trying to create a computer game\program and the main thing that it uses is input from the user, commands, in a JTextField. So I already have a basic text field set up called "question" 
(JTextField question = new JTextField(15);) in a JFrame and an OK button to enter the text. Next is a String "answer". This is: 
     String answer = question.getText().toUpperCase();

This is how the field is set up. Net is the 3 if statements that give an error if no text is entered, if it is not the right word, and of course, the correct answer. They are as follows:

```
Public class ButtonListener extends ActionListener
{
     publix void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
          if(e.getSource() == buttonOK)
          {
           String answer = question.getText().toUpperCase();

          if(answer.length() == 0)
          {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    Window.this,
                    "ERROR: NO INPUT",
                    "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }

          if(answer == "XENIX")
          {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    Window.this,
                    "Welcome, Sir",
                    "Greetings",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }

          if(answer != "XENIX" && answer.length > 0)
          {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    Window.this,
                    "ERROR: INCORECT PASSWORD",
                    "ERROR",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
```

This is how the if statements react when text is entered and the ok button is pressed. Everything works but when I type in "Xenix", it says "ERROR: INCORRECT PASSWORD". The, "Welcome, Sir" message never shows, even though using a print method it shows it is clearly getting "XENIX" from the answer. Why is it not working? Is there another method I'm supposed to use? Please respond soon! Thanks!

Comment: Use `String#equals` to compare `Strings`

Comment: Sorry about the weird layout. Not sure why it posted so funky. If you have a question about Syntax, please ask!

Comment: Layout corrected. Please do read the help information when editing your posts which will explain how to make sure that your code formatting is shown. And as @Reimeus states, do not use `==` to compare Strings as this only compares if the objects are one and the same, which is not what you're interested.

Comment: How would that look, Reimeus?

Comment: @NicholasCreech: click on Mad's link please.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked! But what about when I need to compare is they DON'T equal eachother because now != doesn't work.

Comment: @NicholasCreech do `!equals(...)` instead, then. The `!` character inverts the logic, so it basically says `NOTequals(...)`* (*not actual syntax).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: opposite of .equals???? != doesnt work.

Comment: That was not my comment but rather @Izmaki, and he is giving you bad advice. You would do `if (!someString.equals(otherString)) {`. this is no different from using `!` with any other boolean expression. Avoid thinking in a concrete fashion, but rather use general concepts in new ways in order to move ahead.

Comment: @Izmaki it underlines it saying, "Incompatible operand types String and boolean"

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I see how my comment is slightly confusing - my bad. It should of course have said `!answer.equals("XENIX")`.

Comment: @HoverCraftFullOfEels: Thanks so much! I hate it when a problem has such an easy fix. Thanks everyone else too! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(question.getText() !=null && !question.getText().isEmpty())
{
    String answer = question.getText().toUpperCase();

    if(answer.length() == 0)
    {
        ------------------
        ------------------
    }   

    if(answer.equals("XENIX"))
    {
        ------------------
        ------------------
    }

    if((!answer.equals("XENIX")) && answer.length > 0)
    {
        ------------------
        ------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never compare String's with ==. Use the `equals(...)` method, instead. Edit: cheers. ;)

Comment: Thnx @lzmaki updated the answer